# C++ comparator passing argument problem of complex situation

Tags: c++, c++11

I have class A, in which there is a member variable of class B. And in B, there is a member variable of priority_queue "q" and I want to define a customized comparator class C for it. But for the comparator, the comparison needs a member variable "f_val" from A. Notice that these "f_val" is the same object and I will replace them with a shared pointer but I dont plant to discuss it here.

Since the original code is long, the basic idea is as follows:

```
class C
{
  map<Point,double> f_val;
  C(double f_val1)
  {
    f_val=f_val1;
  }
  bool operator () (const Point &pt1, const Point &pt2)
  {
    return f_val[pt1] > f_val[pt2];
  }

};



class A
{
    B b;
    map<Point,double> f_val;
}

class B
{
    B(map<Point,double> f_val1){f_val=f_val1;}
    priority_queue<Point,vector<Point>,C(f_val)> q;
    map<Point,double> f_val;
}
```

And my problem is this cannot be compiled since f_val is not static when passing to C(). So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see e.g. [this `std::priority_queue` constructor reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) you will see that you can pass a comparator *object* as argument.

So the solution is to use your `B` constructor initializer list to construct and initialize the queue:

```
struct B
{
    map<Point, double>& f_val;
    priority_queue<Point, dequeue<Point>, C> q;

    B(map<Point, double>& f_val1)
        : f_val(f_val1), q(C(f_val1))
    {}
};
```

---

As you can see in the example above, I have used a *reference* to the map. Use a reference for the map in the class `C` as well, to avoid copying and the risk of the maps being out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to specifying a custom comparison type, you can [pass a custom comparator instance to the constructor of `priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue). Construct a `C` object any way that fits your need (ensuring that it is copy-constructible), then pass it to the constructor of `q`.

Given the state of your example (all three classes have an `f_val` map, and no indication of which one is canonical), it's a little difficult to offer more targeted help.

Comment: Updated my question: "Notice that these "f_val" is the same object and I will replace them with a shared pointer but I dont plant to discuss it here."